# Can I change the email for my steam account without logging in?

Tags: account-recovery

I made a Smurf account a while back and forgot my email. Now I can't log in because I forgot the Username/password and email. So is there anything I can do to get it back?

I have the account as a friend on steam tho.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not think it is possible to change the email associated with the account without at least having access to that email inbox.

When you say you forgot your email, do you mean the address? Or you know the address but not the password to access it? If you forgot both you could be in trouble.

The first thing I would try is checking my search history for the last time I was logged into the smurf account email. What provider did you use? Gmail/Yahoo/etc? You can search for those words in your search history and you may be able to find them.

If that fails you could also try contacting Steam and explaining the situation, I know they have an account recovery mechanism but I am not sure if it will help.

To prevent this problem in the future, I would recommend configuring the email of smurf accounts to forward all emails from Stream or other services, to your main account. You can also set up your main email account to organise this forwarded mail into manageable folders.